# Enemy isn't respawning (all code after yield return waitforseconds doesn't get executed)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The code that is after yield return `waitforsec`. in my coroutine that I launch from the enemy doesn't get executed.

Here is my enemy script

```
public void Death()
{
    playerStats.onXpGathered(stats.xpReward);
    if(canRespawn)
    {
        health = stats.maxHealth;
        StartCoroutine(resScript.Respawn(respawnTime, gameObject, spawnPos));
    }
    else
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }        
}
```

Here is my respawn script:

```
public class RespawnScript : MonoBehaviour
{
        
    public IEnumerator Respawn(float cooldown, GameObject enemy, Vector2 spawnPos) 
    {
        //enemy deactivates
        enemy.SetActive(false);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        //nothing past this works for some reason
        print("got past yield return")
        enemy.SetActive(true);
        enemy.transform.position = spawnPos; 
    }
}
```

I tried using a `Time.deltaTime` timer (that works, but there's no way for me to use the void Update function [at least from my knowledge] in a way so it starts when the enemy dies.

I also tried using `WaitForSecondsRealtime` but that didn't change anything.

Note: the death function is on a enemy `GameObject`, the respawn is on a `gameManager` `GameObject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [document](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) says:

> A coroutine also stops if you’ve set SetActive to false to disable the GameObject
> the coroutine is attached to.

Since you deactived the enemy object and the enemy object happened to be the object running the coroutine, the coroutine stopped working as expected.

To solve the problem, you can start a coroutine on a global game object, you mentioned there is a `gameManager` in the scene, If I suppose this `RespawnScript` script is attached to the `gameManager`, you can do this:

```
resScript.StartCoroutine(resScript.Respawn(respawnTime, gameObject, spawnPos));
```

Comment: I already mentioned that the script that has the coroutine is on the game manager

Comment: Yeah the coroutine code is on the game manager, but the object running the coroutine is the object that calls StartCoroutine. Could you notice the difference between my code and yours?